# ESP8266 module get reset

Tags: at-command, esp8266

I have 2 no. of ESP8266 module. I configure them by using AT command as follows.

Module 1 settings

```
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CIPAP="192.168.1.0"
AT+CWSAP="esp_1","",1,0         [Note: for testing no password is set]
AT+CIPAP?                                                                      
    +CIPAP:ip:"192.168.1.0"
    +CIPAP:gateway:"192.168.1.0"
    +CIPAP:netmask:"255.255.255.0"
    OK

AT+CWSAP?                                                                    
    +CWSAP:"esp_1","",1,0,4,0
    OK
```

Module 2 settings

```
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CIPAP="192.168.2.0"
AT+CWSAP="esp_2","",1,0         [Note: for testing no password is set]
AT+CIPAP?                                                                      
    +CIPAP:ip:"192.168.2.0"
    +CIPAP:gateway:"192.168.2.0"
    +CIPAP:netmask:"255.255.255.0"
    OK

AT+CWSAP?                                                                    
    +CWSAP:"esp_2","",1,0,4,0
    OK
```

Now I want to connect to Module 1 from Module 2, so I send following command from Module 2.

```
AT+CWJAP="esp_1",""
  WIFI CONNECTED
  WIFI GOT IP                                                                     
  OK
```

Connection Ok. no problem.

Now I switch off Module 1, and send above command from module 2, my module 2 got reset with following log

```
AT+CWJAP="esp_1",""
     ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)                                
    wdt reset                        
    load 0x40100000, len 816, room 16   
    tail 0                                           
    chksum 0x8d
    load 0x3ffe8000, len 788, room 8 
    tail 12
    chksum 0xcf
    ho 0 tail 12 room 4
    load 0x3ffe8314, len 288, room 12 
    tail 4
    chksum 0xcf
    csum 0xcf

    2nd boot version : 1.2                                                        
      SPI Speed      : 40MHz                                                    
      SPI Mode       : DIO                             
      SPI Flash Size : 32Mbit                               
    jump to run user1                                   
    rlŽô                                                        
    ready
```

Another observation is that.

After above error I restore the setting of Module 2 to factory setting by "AT+RESTORE" command and again configure Module 2 given by above steps.

Now when I fire connect command I got some response, In this case my module is not got reset. (Note: Module 1 is still switch off)

```
AT+CWJAP="esp_1",""
+CWJAP:3                                                                     
FAIL
```

So My question is why module got reset in Test case 1.
What is meaning of "rst cause:4" in error log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "rst cause:4" means WDT reset (watchdog timeout).